# Docker hub/store doesn't show build information

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-cloud

I'm having problems with docker continuous integration.

I setup automated builds in cloud.docker.com for my project, but there is not information at all either in their webs (hub/store) or their api, which shows that my build is not automated.

Docker Cloud looks like this:

[image: Build configuration]

[image: Recent builds]

But in the registry there is no "builds" section:

[image: My project]

I guess that should look like other members projects, something like this:

[image: Other member project]

Also, like I said, using the endpoint: `https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/{user}/{project}/` shows me "**automated build: false**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that, in some way, there is no link between the Docker Cloud automatic builds and Docker Hub ones.

If you create an automated build in Docker Hub, everything works. I don't understand the logic of this, because if you create a repo either in docker cloud or docker hub, they are syncronized as one, but automated builds created on Docker Cloud don't show correctly in Docker Hub/Store.

**Both, the Docker Hub and Docker Store builds will be updated whenever you do a push to your repo or a new build is sent with `docker push`, but the information about the automatic build only will be showed in Docker Cloud if you did it here.**

Comment: I am having the same issue. It is quite confusing. Does this mean that even though dockerhub shows the old build, `docker pull` will in fact download the latest build produced via docker cloud?

Comment: Yes, it does. I've should specified that the only thing that doesn't synchronize between Docker Cloud and Docker Hub is the automatic build information, but, if you check your tags in Docker Hub you will see the "updated" timestamp changes.